Clarification and Proof Details for Theorem 8.4 in Nocedal’s Numerical Optimization
I am studying Theorem 8.4 from Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright, which discusses the application of methods in the Broyden class to a strongly convex quadratic function
$f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $. The theorem is stated as follows:
Suppose that a method in the Broyden class is applied to a strongly convex quadratic function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ where $x_0$ is the starting point and $B_0$ is any symmetric and positive definite matrix. Assume that $_k$ s the exact step length and that $_≥_^$ for all . Then the following statements are true:
i) The iterates converge to the solution in at most  iterations.
ii)The secant equation is satisfied for all previous search directions: $__=_,=−1,…,1$.
iii)If the starting matrix is $B_0=I$ then the iterates are identical to those generated by the conjugate gradient method (see Chapter 5). In particular, the search directions are conjugate: $_^⊤_=0$ for $≠$,
where  is the Hessian of the quadratic function.
iv)If  iterations are performed, we have $_{n+1}=$
While I understand the general statement of the theorem, I am looking for clarification on the following points:
-Can someone outline or reference a rigorous proof for each part of the theorem, particularly for points (ii), (iii), and (iv)?
-For part (iii), how is the equivalence with the conjugate gradient method formally established? Does it rely only on the symmetric positive-definite nature of $B_0$ ?
-In part (iv), is the condition $_{n+1}=$ a direct consequence of satisfying the secant equation for  iterations, or is additional reasoning required?
If possible, I would also appreciate any references to supplementary materials or explanations related to this theorem that go beyond the textbook.
Thank you in advance for your help!
